# Faded in div with jQuery causes content width to be larger than viewport on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, safari

I'm fading in a div with jQuery on a button click. 
Before the div is faded in the website renders as desired.

But when I click the button and the div gets faded in, the site increases in size somehow and I can horizontally. This does not happen if I dont hide and fade in the same div.

[image: Rendered as desired]

[image: The content gets larger than the viewport]

JS

```
$("#stopp").click(function()
    {   
        $("#pil").removeClass("rotatePil");

        getRotationDegrees(hjul);

        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#third").offset().top}, 1500);
        //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1500);

        $("#hvit-boks>h1").fadeOut(500);
        $("#start,#stopp").fadeOut(500);

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("#res").fadeIn(1000);
        }, 500);

        setTimeOut(function()
        {
            $("html, body").stop();
        }, 1500);

    });
```

HTML

```
                <h1>Snurr lykkehjulet!</h1>

                <button id="start">SNURR!</button>

                <button id="stopp">STOPP</button>

                <div id="res">

                    <span id="big-res">Du fikk 145</span>

                    <p>

                        Et lykkehjul er tilfeldig. Det er imidlertid ikke tilfeldig hva kundene våre synes om skadeoppgjøret vårt. 
                        Faktisk får vi 8,6 i gjennomsnittsscore på en skala fra 0-10 når de blir spurt om hvor fornøyde de er etter en 
                        skade. Det skal vi være stolte av!


                    </p>

                    <button id="again">PRØV IGJEN</button>

                </div> <!-- /RES -->

            </div> <!-- /HVIT BOKS -->
```

CSS

```
#hvit-boks
{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#hvit-boks h1
{
    font-size: 30px;
}

#left
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#big-res
{
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
}

#res p
{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
}
```

Comment: A fiddle might be helpful to understand clearly,...

Comment: try with `css` `body {overflow-x: hidden;}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my solution will work in your case or not. but I would like you to try following solution.

can you please try and add following css to your code.

```
#res
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

please comment me back, if it works or not. I will come up with better solution if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: can you share it on fiddle, so I can try and play around it?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue in fiddle.